# Sorting an array while inserting new item Linear Time O(n)?

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory, space-complexity

> How can I sort my array while inserting new element? Firstly it is
>   empty. When I add new item it will be sorted. Can I do this while
>   inserting in O(n) space time?

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the array<sup>1</sup>, and insert the element between the existing elements (`a[i] < new <= a[i+1]`, which is the first position `a[i] < new`). Then shift each existing element in the array following where the new element is inserted by one index (`a[j+1] = a[j] for j > i`). Use a temp variable to keep the floating value as the array is being shifted. This can also be slightly changed to iterate backward and then no explicit temp variable is needed as the shift is done prior-to the insert.

Each *individual* element's insert is thus O(n), which is *O(n*n) overall* for n inserts. <sup>1</sup>Even if needing to create a new array, such as in languages with a fixed array size, space is O(2n) which is the same as O(n). The Big-O time complexity remains the same regardless of shifting existing elements or allocating a new array and copying all elements.

Space allocation costs can be "amortized" by pre-allocating slack in the array structure. This is a quality of implementation concern only. Using a binary search to find the insert point does not change the "worst case" Big-O bounds: consider when insertion always occurs at the first index.